# Integration with $\sin(t)$ as the variable.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I am currently working on a question about Calculus on Manifolds and ran into an integral that I'm confused about. How would you evaluate:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(t) d\sin(t)$$

The answer is $\pi$, by simplifying the above to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^{2\pi}dt$$
I tried using u-sub but I think I'm missing something here. Am I supposed to use the identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$?

Comment: Just make use of the fact that $d\sin{(t)}=\cos{(t)}dt$, the first integral you wrote down understood in the [Riemann Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral) sense

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295383/integration-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), a generalization of the Riemann integral. Since $\sin(t)$ is everywhere continuously differentiable, we have that the integral is equivalent to

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(t)\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sin(t)\right)\,dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\big(\cos(t)\big)}^2\,dt$$

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: I got the answer, but where did the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the integral come from in the solution someone else provided?

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.