# What does integrating a function wrt to another function intuitively mean?

Tags: integration

I sometimes see stuff that is of the following notation:

$$ \int f(x) dG(x) $$

I reckon a specific example would be:

$$ \int x \operatorname{d \sin(x)} $$

How can one intuitively interpret this. Does this mean that we're compressing and stretching the x-axis by a sin function?

Comment: see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/14539).

Comment: @Dando18 many thanks -- will check it out.

Comment: [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

Comment: what does actually $ \int x \operatorname{d \sin(x)}$ mean ? formally.. 

Isn't just  substitution ? i.e.,  $\int x  \cos(x) \operatorname{d x}$

Comment: @Ashkan -- it mean integrate x w.r.t to sin(x) -- my understanding is that it is not a substitution

Comment: My question was exactly that  . what does integrating $x$ w.r.t $\sin$ mean?

Comment: @Ashkan that was my question too :-) -- I'm trying to precisely understand what the notation means intuitively.

Comment: I thought You already knew formal definition but  want get some intuition about that definition.  !

Comment: @Ashkan -- ah I see --  I actually work in the reverse most of the time -- I like to get a good feel of the notation means intuitively and then try to relate that to the formal definition

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295383/219176