# Solid angle integral

Tags: calculus

In the book of [Giasser Cosmic Rays and particles](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cosmic-rays-and-particle-physics/C81BA71195ADFC89EFCC2C565B617702). It says that the geometrical acceptance of two parallel plates of area $A1$ and $A2$, separated by a distance $d$ is:

$$A = \Delta \Omega \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\varphi_{1} \int_{0}^{r_{max}}r_{1}dr_{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi_{2}\int_{\xi }^{1}cos\left ( \theta \right )d \ cos\ \theta$$

But how is the last integral evaluated, I have never seen that form. Is it considering that the $cos \ \theta$ is the variable of integration?

Comment: Why no  distance $d$ appears anywhere in the expression?

Comment: Apparently the term $\xi$ is $\xi \left ( r_{1},\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2} \right )$ is a term of the angular integral, that is determined by the shape of the upper plane, but there is no explicit form on how this function is obtained; could by geometric construction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a change of variable. So we have

$$\int\cos(\theta)d\cos(\theta)=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2}+C$$

since $\int\cos(\theta)d\cos(\theta)$ is a function such that its derivative wrt $\cos(\theta)$ is $\cos(\theta)$. See [Integration of a function with respect to another function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295383/integration-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function).