# A question on integrating a function, with respect to another function?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification, area, stieltjes-integral

I've been asked to find the area described by
$$A={ (x,y),  y^2 \leqslant2x;  and, y\geqslant 4x-1 } $$
which is effectively the following area(If I can insert a graph using mathJax, please let me know in the comments)

The area is the area that's shaded both blue and red
[image: The area is the area that's shaded both blue and red]

The normal way to find this is to set up multiple integrals that remove undesired areas, however, this method requires one to be hyperattentive of what they're doing, so I was thinking of integrating let's say the equation $y^2=2x$ , with respect to $y=4x+1$ , with the bounds being the points at which the line intersects the parabola. Thus, the integral would be

$$\int_{0.125}^{0.5} \sqrt{2x} {d({4x-1)}}$$
which is the same as $$ 4 \int \sqrt{2x} dx$$, when evaluated as an indefinite integral

I'm hoping the above step "transforms" the graph(sorry if the terminology is wrong)

the new bounds of the integral as given by $4x-1= 0.125$ which implies the lower limit is $0.28125$ , and the upper limit $0.375$

thus the new integral is $$ 4 \int_{0.02815}^{0.375} \sqrt{2x} dx$$

I have come across answers like this [on integrating one function, with respect to another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295383/integration-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function#:%7E:text=When%20solving%20problems%2C%20you%20just,2x77%2BC.), however, the way they have done the u-sub there is confusing me, so I'm asking this as a new question, this time with the primary point of interest being areas

Is this conceptually right, and if not, where am I going wrong?

footnote:- For those interested, this problem is from the 2015 JEE mains paper, a competitive engineering entrance exam in India. I'm aware that solutions are available online, but I wanted to know if this approach is correct.

Comment: The best I can say is that I think this is accidentally right. If you try this technique on another pair of intersecting curves I don't think you'll get the same answer.

Comment: I think his would only work if I were to find the area between a line and a curve, right?

Comment: Oh, why is that? Thanks for the reply

Comment: By the way, what I would call the “normal” way to do this problem is to integrate vertically. The difference of the $x$-coordinates is $(y+1)/4 - y^2/2$, and the limits of integration are the $y$-coordinates of the intersections.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I still have to subtract regions, which is what I want to avoid

Comment: But in what situations could multiplying take the place of subtracting? This is my biggest concern with your method.

Comment: Where did I multiply? I multiplied because of the differential element

Comment: In my answer, the differential element, was 4x-1 which is why I multiplied by 4

Comment: As this question hasn't received any answers yet, I'll be offering a bounty on it shortly, so even if you have an answer, please wait until I offer the bounty so  that you can claim the same

Comment: It has been suggested that you try it with a different example. Why haven't you taken this excellent advice?

Comment: I'll do that now, sorry

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. But I'm not sure I understand why

Comment: When a method works, it makes sense to ask why it works, that is, to ask for a proof. When a method doesn't work, it's generally because there was no good reason to expect it would work, and that's about all one can say.

Comment: OK. Thank you.!